# Why does subsetting include NA rows but filter does not?

Tags: r, subset

When I subset a dataframe according to certain conditions, the result I get is the subsetted conditions AND NA rows.

When i use filter, it only gives me the filtered rows.

SO subsetting I may get 20 rows (10 REAL and 10 NA rows) BUT filtering, I get 10 rows (ALL Real).

Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

It is a behavior specified in the documentation of `?filter`

> The filter() function is used to subset a data frame, retaining all rows that satisfy your conditions. To be retained, the row must produce a value of TRUE for all conditions. Note that when a condition evaluates to NA the row will be dropped, unlike base subsetting with [.

Main reason is that any comparison using operators `==` or `>` or `<` returns `NA` if the element is an `NA` as

```
NA > 5
#[1] NA

NA == 5
#[1] NA
```

However, if we use `%in%`, it returns `FALSE`

```
NA %in% 5
#[1] FALSE
```

So, in `filter`, if we need to also return the `NA` elements, use an `|` condition

```
df1 %>%
  filter(col1 == 5|is.na(col1))
```